# Proof involving inner product and orthonormal sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

> Suppose $S = {[v_1, . . . , v_n]}$ is an orthonormal set and $v = α_1v_1 + · · · + α_nv_n$.
>   Show that
>   $\langle v, v\rangle =$ $α_1\overline{α_1} + · · · + α_n\overline{α_n} $.

Here I tried subbing in $v$, as a linear combination of vectors in $S$, into the inner product, but I became tangled up because I know that if the set is orthonormal, the inner product of any two elements in the set is zero, so my proof diminished. Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: Are you sure $\langle v_i,v_i \rangle$ vanishes?

Comment: Well, I thought that if you have an inner product of any two elements of an orthonormal set, that will equal zero? Given that $v$ is any element from $S$ would it not vanish?

Comment: No, not of any two. Just of those with different indices!

Comment: Why would that be the case?

Comment: By definition! One of the axioms of an inner product says $\langle v,v \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle v,v \rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow v=0$.

Comment: Remember that *orthonormal* means *orthogonal* and *unit length*.

Answer (score 1):

The number $\langle v,v\rangle$ is the sum$$\sum_{k,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}\alpha_j\overline{\alpha_k}\langle v_j,v_k\rangle.\tag1$$But$$\langle v_j,v_k\rangle=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }j=k\\0&\text{ if }j\neq k\end{cases}$$and therefore $(1)$ is equal to$$\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\overline{\alpha_j}.$$

Comment: Okay, thank you. How do you know that the inner product of any vector with itself in this case is equal to 1? Sorry if I'm being silly.

Comment: Because $\langle v_j,v_j\rangle=\lVert v_j\rVert^2=1$. Don't forget that your set is orthonormal.